# What is the best way to unscramble words with PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm

I have a word list and I want to unscramble words using this word list, in PHP.

It seems to me that PHP doesn't have a built-in function that does this. So could someone please suggest a good algorithm to do this, or at least point me in the right direction?

EDIT: edited to add example

So basically, what I'm talking about is I have a list of words:

```
   apple
   banana
   orange
```

Then, I'm given a bunch of jumbled letters.

```
   pplea
   nanaba
   eroang
```

Comment: Please give an example of what you mean.

Comment: So you're saying you have a dictionary (a big list of correctly spelled words) and you want to use this to take scrambled letters and decide what word the letters are supposed to make.  Correct?

Comment: Are you possible talking about perumations of letters in a word? How do you plan on matching them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a dictionary of known words:

```
foreach ($list as $word)
{
  if (count_chars($scrambled_word,1) == count_chars($word,1))
    echo "$word\n";
}
```

Edit: A simple optimization would be to move the `count_chars($scrambled_word,1))` outside the loop since it never changes:

```
$letters = count_chars($scrambled_word,1)
foreach ($list as $word)
{
  if ($letters == count_chars($word,1))
    echo "$word\n";
}
```

Comment: I should have a disclaimer that I consider this neither good nor best (in terms of efficiency), but only that it's simple to implement.

Comment: This /is/ pretty clever. Given the size of word list(about 10,000 words), I'd say this wouldn't really hurt my run time. Thanks.

Comment: Might want to add `strtolower()` if you are unsure of the letter case.

Comment: Jerry's solution is much more efficient that a scan each time.

Answer (score 3):

Warning: I rarely use PHP, so this is dealing only with a general algorithm that should work in almost any language, not anything specific to PHP.

Presumably you have a word in which the letters have been rearranged, and you want to find what word(s) could be made from those letters.

If that's correct, the general idea is fairly simple: take a copy of your word list, and sort the letters in each word into alphabetical order. Put the sorted and unsorted versions of each word side by side, and sort the whole thing by the sorted words (but keeping each unsorted word along with its sorted version). You may want to collapse duplicates together, so that (for example) instead of {abt : bat} and {abt : tab}, you have: {abt: bat, tab}

Then, to match up a scrambled word, sort its letters in alphabetical order. Look for matches in your dictionary (since it's sorted, you can use a binary search). When you find a match, the result is the word (or words) associated with that sorted letter group. Using the example above, if the scrambled word was "tba", you'd sort it to get "abt", then look up "abt" to get "bat" and "tab".

Edit: As @Moron pointed out in the comments, sorting and binary search aren't really crucial points in themselves. The basic points are to turn all equivalent inputs into identical keys, then use some sort of fast lookup by key to find the word(s) for that key.

Sorting the letters in each word is one easy way to turn equivalent inputs into identical keys. Sorting the list and doing a binary search is one easy way to do fast lookups by key.

In both cases, there are quite a few alternatives. I'm not at all sure the alternatives are likely to improve performance a lot, but they certainly could.

Just for example, instead of a pure binary search you could have a second level of index that told you where the keys starting with 'a' were, the keys starting with 'b', and so on. Given that a couple of extremely frequently-used letters are near the beginning of the alphabet ('e' and 'a', for example) you *might* be better off sorting the words so that relatively uncommon letters ('q', 'z', etc.) are toward the front of the key, and the most commonly used letters are at the end. This would give that first lookup based on the initial character the greatest discrimination.

On the sort/binary search side, there are probably more alternatives, and probably better arguments to be made in favor of using something else. Hash tables typically allow lookups in (nearly) constant time. Tries can reduce storage substantially, especially when many words share a common prefix. The only obvious disadvantage is that the code for either one is probably more work (though PHP's array type is hash-based, so you could probably use it quite nicely).

Comment: Storing the word list in the `{abt: bat, tab}` format is probably the best solution in terms of a balance of efficiency and effort.

Comment: @konforce: Quite true -- if you're doing this often at all, you'd want to initialize your dictionary once, and just use it after that.

Comment: @rgin: Given what PHP is (mostly) good at, I'd probably use MySQL (or whatever) to handle the sorting, searching, etc., part and use PHP to read the input, possibly sort that individual word, and issue a query against the database.

Comment: Instead of sorting the whole list (and doing a later binary search), you can use a hashtable or a trie (which can save memory but is probably complicated to code). +1 anyway.

Comment: @Jerry: Yeah not finding fault with the answer. Just hoping you will edit your answer to include that :-)

Comment: The only reason I commented is to avoid near duplicate answers and not lose information, so I deleted my answer and commented on yours. A side effect of this is that potentially useful information is left lying around in comments instead of in the answer, unless someone edits it in...

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to unscramble in `O(log p + n)` where

```
p = size of dictionary 
n = length of word to be unscrambled
```

Assume a constant, `c`, the most occurrences of some letter within any word plus 1.
Assume a constant, `k`, the number of letters in the alphabet.
Assume a constant, `j`, the most number of words that can share the same hash or letter-sorted version.

Initialization of `O(p)` space:
1. Using the dictionary, `D`, create an associated list of letter sorted words, `L`, which will be size at most `p` since each word has a one sorted version.
2. Associate another column to `L` with a numerical hash of integers which can range `[0, c^k-1]`. 
3. For each word in `L`, generate its hash with the following function:
`hash(word) = 0 if word is empty or (c^i + hash(remaining substring of the word))`
where `i` is the zero-based alphabet index of the first letter.

Algorithm:
1. In `O(n)`, determine hash, `h`, of the letter sorted version of the word in question.
2. In `O(log p)`, search for the hash in `L`.
3. In `O(n)`, list `j` associated words of length `n`.

Comment: Theoretically, `j` here could grow in `O(n!)` if your language was dense enough, but I don't think that applies to known spoken languages.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Answer (score 0):

The slow option would be to generate all *permutations* of the letters in a scrambled word, then probe them via [pspell_check()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-check.php).

If you however can use a raw dictionary text file, then the best option is to just use a regular expression to scan it:

```
$dict = file_get_contents("words.txt");  // one word per line

$n = strlen($word);
if (preg_match('/^[$word]{$n}$/im', $dict, $match)) {
    print $match[0];
}
```

I'm quite certain PCRE is significantly faster at searching for permutations than PHP and the guessing approach.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of PHP's array functions since they can solve this for you.

```
$words = array('hello', 'food', 'stuff', 'happy', 'fast');
$scrambled_word = 'oehll';

foreach ($words as $word)
{
    // Same length?
    if (strlen($scrambled_word) === strlen($word))
    {
        // Convert to an array and match
        if( ! array_diff(str_split($word), str_split($scrambled_word)))
        {
            print "Your word is: $word";
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, you look for something the same length - then you ask PHP to see if all the letters are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a really large list of words and want this unscramble operation to be fast, I'd try putting the word list into a database.  Next add a field to your word list table that is the sum of the ascii values of the word, and then add an index on this ascii sum.

Whenever you want to retrieve a list of possible matches just search the word table for ascii sums that match the sum of the scrambled letters. Keep in mind that you may have a few false matches so you'll have to compare all of the matched words to ensure they contain only the letters of your scrambled word (but the result set should be pretty small).

If you don't want to use a database you could implement the same basic idea using a file, just sort the list by the sum value for faster retrieval of all matches.

Example Data assumes all lowercase (a=97, b=98, c=99, ...)
  bat => 311,
  cat => 312, ...

Example php function to figure out the sum for a word

```
function asciiSum($word) {
  $characters = str_split(strtolower($word));
  $sum = 0;
  foreach($characters as $character) {
    $sum += ord($character);
  }
  return $sum;
}
```

Even faster: add another field to the database that represents the string length, then you can search for words based on an ascii sum and a string length which would further reduce the number of false matches you would need to check for.